# Does a purely textual headless CMS exist (or similar service) exist?

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system

I create a hard-coded simple landing page for our customer. Said customer has changed their mind and wants to be able to edit the text on the landing page themselves. Does a service exist that would allow my customer to fill out some text, and my webpage (frontend only) to fetch these texts and plug them into their respective DOM elements?

The way I'm imaginging it is this:
Me (admin) can create some input fields for my customer on said service
My customer can login and populate these fields
My webpage (through JSON or similar) can fetch my customer's text inputs and use them to populate the respective elements on the landing page. I guess something along these lines of https://prismic.io/ but simpler (not requiring react, but working with vanilla JS and html).

I have looked and couldn't find anything. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'd say a PHP page to show the content with a simple MySql database behind it. You can then have a password protected php page with HTML form with the text fields that you want to send to your database and then pull out onto the PHP content page.

Comment: Hey @ultrarun, does is certainly an option. Thank you. I was hoping to find a service that would that would free me of having to create + roughly design another PHP page as well as connect it to a MySql Database. I'm just surprised that so far I haven't found such service. I cannot be the only one looking for this.

Comment: You could just use WordPress and have a simple home page and set it up like a landing page, no site menu etc. All of he PHP/MySql is taken care of in WP.

Comment: True that! But if possible, I would like to remain with simple html and js. Also has to do with external requirements. What I was thinking, is I could use google sheets, share that document with my client, and then use the json api. But all of this leads me to think: There must be a service. And if not, I might make one.